# Sonarqube quality gate configuration

Tags: sonarqube

I am facing a small challenge while I try to set a custom quality gate in Sonar for "bugs" i.e. blocker should not be more than 0.

Instead the quality gate is picking the category "code smells" and showing the results from there.

Is there a way of how this can be corrected?

I am using sonarqube version 8.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in 0 blocker bugs, you should be checking *Reliability rating is not worse than D*. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/#header-6

Comment: Thanks Raspy for your prompt reply... I intend to use the gates as blocker bugs, critical bugs and major bugs.. but I only see 1 reliability rating option that I can use.. is there a way to accommodate all 3 variations in the quality gate?

Comment: Rating will be the lowest of all, so for example if you have at least 1 blocker bug, it does not matter how many other types of bugs you have, the rating will be E. If you fix all the blocker bugs, but still have at least 1 critical bug, the rating will be D and so on. Therefore if you want to make sure that there are no blocker bugs, no critical bugs and no major bugs, you must check for rating not worse than B.